# Adding a new player with keys WASD

Tags: java, class, processing, move, intersect

I am really new to programming. For my class, I am making a game and I would like to add a seconds player to the game. At the moment, there are black circles that appear randomly in the game and keep growing. You are a circle and you need to avoid the circles for as long as possible. Once you intersect with one the game ends. This circle is controlled with the arrow keys. However I would like to add a new circle with the keys WASD. This is my code so far. But when the game starts I can see the circle but I cannot move it.

The main part of the code I am worried about is ProcessUserInput2 because that is the code that controls WASD. I have not pasted in my entire code. Any help would be much appreciated

```
void draw()
{
  //Call functions

  if (gameState == 0)//Start Screen
  {
    ProccessUserInput_Start(); //this function is in a separate tab. It processes what the player inputs into the computer, and then translates it into commands
    Render_Start(); 
    savedTime = millis();
  }
  if (gameState == 1)//Game Playing Screen
  {

    ProcessUserInput1(); //this is for the arrow keys
    ProcessUserInput2(); //this is for WASD
    Render();
    totalTime = 40000; //Timer (in millis)
    for (growingEllipse e:ellipses)
    {
      e.ellipseGrow();
      e.rendering();
    }

void ProcessUserInput1()
//Move circle Left, Right, Up or Down using arrow keys
{
  if (keyPressed)
  {
    if (keyCode == LEFT)//Move Left
    {
      x1 = x1 - 2;
    }
    if (keyCode == RIGHT)//Move Right
    {
      x1 = x1 + 2;
    }
    if (keyCode == UP)//Move Up
    {
      y1 = y1 - 2;
    }
    if (keyCode == DOWN)//Move Down
    {
      y1 = y1 + 2;
    }
  }
}

  void ProcessUserInput2()
//Move circle Left, Right, Up or Down using arrow keys
{
  if (keyPressed)
  {
    if (keyCode == 'A')//Move Left
    {
      x2 = x2 - 2;
    }
    if (keyCode == 'D')//Move Right
    {
      x2 = x2 + 2;
    }
    if (keyCode == 'W')//Move Up
    {
      y2 = y2 - 2;
    }
    if (keyCode == 'S')//Move Down
    {
      y2 = y2 + 2;
    }
  }
}

void Render()
{
  background(255);
  fill(255, 228, 196);
  ellipse (x1, y1, r1, r1);
  ellipse (x2, y2, r1, r1);
  //draw circle for player
}
```

If possible, could any really good programmers give me their email so that I can ask them questions? I still need to add in a few more items such as inheritance and function overloading. I used the Processing application for this.

Comment: nottice you are catching only `caps` char

Answer (score 0):

You're using the keyCode variable, which only works with things like the arrow keys that don't have associated characters.

Instead, you might want to use the key variable, which is a char and contains the character typed.

More info here: http://staticvoidgames.com/tutorials/intermediateConcepts/keyboardInput

Edit: Also, as Jordi said, you're only catching upper-case letters. And please don't ask for email, as that defeats the whole point of public sites like this.